# cannot update a row with a new datetime value ef codefirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, linq-to-sql

**Edit**
The query is correct, the error I was getting was due to the fact that the logout fx below was called twice, once from html href and another from ajax.  The ajax call had the UID while the Html had null, hence exception was thrown -- the html was called later.  Thank you for your inputs.  Since I am new to stackoverflow, I am not sure how to treat the answers/comments as they are all right.

How do I update a row with a new datetime value?

```
          try
            {
                var last = (from l in db.loginActivity
                                 where l.UID.Equals(_uid)
                                 orderby l.LastLogin descending
                                 select l).FirstOrDefault();

                last.LastLogout = DateTime.Now;
                db.Entry(last).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

When I used the FirstOrDefault() -> error: object ref not set to an instance of an object.
When I used the First() -> error: sequence contains no element.
Well, the database has several records.  I have used this snippet somewhere and it works like a charm, only when the updated cells weren't of datetime type. 
Any advise?

Comment: That means it's not finding records in the database table that meet your criteria. What are `l.UID` and `_uid`

Comment: That was the first check (with linqpad4) I did to ensure the data exist and it did.

Comment: Regardless of what you found, zero records in db.loginActivity are being found based on the criteria you are passing. So, what are `l.UID` and `_uid`? Also, why are you using `l.UID.Equals(_uid)` instead of `l.UID == _uid`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that no record with a matching `UID` was found, so therefore `last` is null. You need to check that it's not null:

```
var last = ...;
if (last != null) {
    last.LastLogout = DateTime.Now;
    db.Entry(last).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Alternatively, since you're doing this in a try/catch, you could use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` and just catch the exception `First` throws when it doesn't find a record.

As for why `last` is coming back null, set a breakpoint and make sure `_uid` is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like no items satisfy your filter condition: where l.UID.Equals(_uid)
Did you try to remove "where" from the query?